# Работа с масками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли в Python 3.4 обозначение всех расширений, то есть:

```
mask = input('Росширение файла: ')
```

введя сюда символ всех расширений, получить список файлов со всеми расширениями в каталоге.

Интересует реализация поиска по всем расширениям кроме **exe**.

```
import os
import fnmatch

path = input('Директория: ')
mask = input('Росширение файла: ')
pattern = input('Сигнатура: ')

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, mask):
            inp = open(os.path.join(dirpath, file_name), 'r')
            for line in inp:
                if pattern in line:
                    print(inp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Символа всех расширений нет, но вашу задачу легко можно решить с помощью функции `splitext` из модуля `os.path`, которая разбивает имя файла на основную часть и расширение с точкой:

```
$ python
>>> from os.path import splitext
>>> splitext('file.txt')
('file', '.txt')
>>> splitext('file.')
('file', '.')
>>> splitext('file')
('file', '')
```

Ваш пример будет выглядеть так:

```
import os
from os.path import splitext

path = input('Директория: ')
pattern = input('Сигнатура: ')

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files:
        fn, fext = splitext(file_name)
        if fext != '.exe':
            inp = open(os.path.join(dirpath, file_name), 'r')
            for line in inp:
                if pattern in line:
                    print(inp)
```

Можно немного обобщить код, вынеся список расширений-исключений в отдельную переменную:

```
EXCL_EXTS = ('.exe', )

...

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files:
        fn, fext = splitext(file_name)
        if fext not in EXCL_EXTS:
            ...
```