# Получить список EXE файлов в папке

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, exe

Есть способ получить список всех файлов и папок в определённой деректории.

```
import os
 
url_to_directory = r"C:\Program Files\Python310"
files = os.listdir(url_to_directory)
print(files)
```

Можно ли через os или через split получить список только exe файлов?

Comment: ответ был дан тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441922/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8?rq=1

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с масками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441922/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем glob

```
import glob

url_to_directory = r"C:\Program Files\Python310"

lst = glob.glob(f'{url_to_directory}/*.exe')
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем pathlib

```
import pathlib

url_to_directory = r"C:\Program Files\Python310"
list(pathlib.Path(url_to_directory).glob('*.exe'))
```